# DomSanitizer throwing an error

Tags: html, angularjs, angular5, angular-dom-sanitizer

I am trusting the URL with.. DomSanitizer as below:

```
myFunction(videoLoc:any):void { 
    videoLoc = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(videoLoc); 
}
```

but getting an error on console:

> GET unsafe:myFunction(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c9F5kMUfFKk)

My HTML code is as below:

```
<tr *ngFor="let fetch of fetchApi.data.featured">
  <td>
     <video width="320" height="240" controls>                                                                                                                                              
     <source src=myFunction({{fetch.video_location}})>
     </video>
  </td>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
</tr>
```

That is the reason, I could not render my videos on an HTML page. What is the mistake that I am doing?

Comment: can you try `myFunction(videoLoc:any):void { 
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(videoLoc); 
}`

Comment: Again the same error

Comment: now set this `<source [src]="myFunction(fetch.video_location)">`

Comment: I did this, but now getting an error of `TypeError: Cannot read property 'bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl' of undefined
    at FetchApiComponent.push../src/app/fetch-api/fetch-`

Comment: can you print on console.log url like `myFunction(videoLoc:any):void { console.log(videoLoc);
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(videoLoc); 
}`

Comment: Giving me URL : `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c9F5kMUfFKk`

Comment: check value of this `console.log(this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(videoLoc));`

Comment: It is throwing an error

Comment: what error it is throwing ?

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl' of undefined at FetchApiComponent.push../src/app/fetch-api/fetch-

Comment: debug this `console.log(this.sanitizer)`

Answer (score 0):

Your template seems to be wrong, it should be

```
<source [src]="myFunction(fetch.video_location)">
```

and just return the videoLocation after sanitizing it

```
myFunction(videoLoc:any):void {
 return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(videoLoc);
}
```

or you can handle this with a Pipe,

```
@Pipe({ name: 'safe' })
export class SafePipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}
  transform(url) {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url);
  }
}
```

and then,

```
  <source [src]="mfetch.video_location | safe">
```

Comment: I did this, but still getting an error of `TypeError: Cannot read property 'bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl' of undefined at FetchApiComponent.push../src/app/fetch-api/fetch-api`

Comment: Again throwing an error with the use of pipe - `Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
The pipe 'safe' could not be found`

Comment: you need to add the pipe under providers in module.ts

Comment: did you create a pipe?

Comment: This is my code in component : `@Pipe({ name: 'safe' })
export class FetchApiComponent implements OnInit, PipeTransform {
  transform(url) {
     return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url);
  }`. 
This is what I did in HTML :
`<tr *ngFor="let fetch of fetchApi.data.featured">
    <td ></td>
   <td> {{fetch.id | json}} </td>
   <td>{{fetch.video_location}}</td>
<td><video width="320" height="240" controls>                                   
  <source [src]="fetch.video_location | safe"></video></td>                                                           
  </tr>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172873/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-n-sharma).